# How to fix this sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I am writing a math paper and my teacher said there are some English errors in the sentence that I use below; but, I don't know how to fix it.

**See Conway's book for more information that set A is closed.**

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Let me make one thing clear here. Are you asking for proofreading?

Comment: What does a math teacher know about English?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that requests for proofreading are explicitly off-topic, but furthermore, there are no obvious errors in your sentence. It might not make sense in context, but you have not provided us with any context. I strongly recommend you take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of how to present a question that is answerable in our format. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may also be of interest, though you should note that all of Stack Exchange expects you to demonstrate your own research first.

Comment: @MikeR No just grammar checking.

Comment: What does a math teacher know about grammar?

Comment: @Stan I don't know this sentence is pretty clear to me. Do you find any English mistakes?

Comment: I don't; but, I'm a math teacher.

Comment: Ask your teacher. They may deprecate your use of the term "information" and your inadequate citation as a matter of style in your discipline, and their department may seek to push responsibility for instruction in these subtleties onto the English department; but there is no evident error of English diction, morphology or syntax.

Comment: @Stan By the same token, what does an English teacher know about math?

Comment: @StoneyB My sentiments too. Let's have a beer together and talk about art. : )

Comment: 'See Conway's book for more information that set A is closed' is unacceptable. If Caernarvon's book says that set A is closed, Conway's book can't give you more information that set A is closed. (That would be like saying 'X told Y it was 10 am, and Z added further information that it was 10 am'.) It can corroborate Caernarvon's reasoning/finding / add further arguments in support of Caernarvon's claim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can find no indication that there is a problem with your English construction. Perhaps it's the meaning of your statement — the significance of it.

Perhaps your instructor has a problem with how you refer to Conway's book - the reference.

Is Conway's book specifically about set A and closed sets; or, is the reason set A is closed dealt with somewhere within the comprehensive content of Conway's work on Set Theory?

Might one see Conway's book for more information ***about why*** set A is closed? If this is true, the instructor would be making a comment about the significance of your advice.

It could be that your instructor gave you a misguided answer sending you in the wrong direction for the correct response. It might have been for your choice of words.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think he wants me to use about why instead!

Answer (score 0):

Your instructor might be looking for something like:

> See Conway's book for more information **as to why** set A is closed.

or

> See Conway's book for more information **that proves** set A is closed.

or

> More information of set A's closure can be seen in Conway's book.

The 'correct' structure of the sentence really depends on what your instructor is looking for. Honestly, they probably don't know themselves. I hope this is at least somewhat helpful.

Comment: Actually, the school probably *does* have a standard for citing texts and it probably looks more like "The course text shows why Set A must be closed (Conway, 78)" than any of the examples we've been providing. It's academic writing. ;-)

Comment: I didn't initially view this a citation, but rather a recommendation. Anyway, the citation wouldn't be "(Conway, 78)". You have already stated the authors name in the sentence, so you would only need the page number in the citation. That's assuming there is only one book by that author referenced in the bibliography. Although, it really depends on which standard you are using for your citations. This whole thread is a toss-up because there isn't sufficient information.

Comment: Right. (Well, my example, above, used only the author's name in the parentheses, but if there were only one course text, you could even leave that out, too. But page numbers are normally expected when making an assertion and citing where we can find proof. I think we can agree on that.

Answer (score 0):

The intended meaning of your sentence could be correctly re-phrased multiple ways:

"See Conway's book for more information that set A is closed." (original/incorrect)

"See Conway's book for proof that set A is closed."

"For an explanation of why set A is closed, see pages 78–80 of Conway's book."

"Conway explains why Set A is closed on pp. 78-80 of the course text."

"The reason set A is closed is explained on pages 78–80 of the course text by Conway."

Note: My choice of "pp 78–80" is arbitrary. I don't have your text. But it is pretty standard to show page numbers when citing references in academic papers. If "Conway's book" is the course text, and you aren't using multiple texts by the same author, and the reader is expected to know which text is meant, course texts are frequently just cited as the author's name and page numbers, with or without a comma between, depending on the standard. Find out what the standard is at your school and use the standard when citing texts.

So that might best look like: "Conway proves that Set A must be closed (Conway, 78–80)."

https://uca.edu/cwc/quick-help/apa-basics/apa-in-text-citation-models/  Provides some examples of in-text citation in the academic world.